# Creating a horizontal list that scrolls automatically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I created a horizontal list of pictures that can scroll.  But I want it to automatically start scrolling upon page load (or actually more specifically when the user scrolls down the page to the part of the horizontal list of pictures).  But to start off, how do I get it to automatically scroll without the user?

Here's my css code so far:

```
#horizontalscroll {
    width: auto;
    height:210px;
    border: 2px;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    border: 5px solid;
    border-color:#27303E;
}

#horizontalscrollpictures {
    white-space: nowrap;
    min-height:210px;
    max-height:210px;
    border-right: 2px solid;
    border-color:#27303E;
}
```

I feel like I'll have to use JQuery or JavaScript for that?  Correct me if I'm wrong.

Thanks!

Comment: I think you should google for "javascript marquee".

Comment: If you want to start scrolling horizontally on page load, you can use marquee but if you want to start only when the user scrolls down the page to the part of the horizontal list of pictures, then yes you have to use jquery

Comment: hmm alright thanks I'll look it up thanks!